# How to assign the function return array to the other array

Tags: vba, ms-word, vb6

I want to assign the function return array to the other array.

But there is always error,I don't know how to fix it.

If I don't want to use variant,How can I fix it?

```
Private Sub SomeSub()
     Dim arrFindRange() As Range  --> This is word vba range object
     arrFindRange = FuncReturn()  --> This code will Error
End Sub

Private Function FuncReturn() as Range()
     Dim arrFindRange() As Range
     //.. do something else ..//
     FuncReturn = arrFindRange
End Function
```

Comment: The Range object is an object as you correctly state. It requires the `Set` key word when a value is assigned to it. `Set FuncReturn = arrFindRange` and, of course, `Set  arrFindRange = FuncReturn`

Comment: It's no work...I had tried it.

Comment: On which line of code do you get an error? Which is the error you get?